# iPod to iphone transferring

Tags: iphone

I wanted to transfer an app from my iPod to my iPhone. The the app I paid for was on my iPod. And I'm trying not to pay for the app again. Is there a way I can transfer the app from my iPod to my iPhone without using any laptop or computer?

Comment: Did you try to redownload it from the App Store, using the same account as from your iPod?

Answer (score 1):

Simply browse for the app on your iPhone and download it from there under the account that you paid for the app originally.

Follow [this apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201272#apps) on how to download a previously paid app.